# the synonym to 'admitted to a university'

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms

What was the word that starts with 'm' and means admitted to a university? I read it somewhere and wanted to use but forgot it.

Comment: There's a good article on matriculation [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriculation). It can have quite different meanings at different universities and in different countries, so (as @DavidSiegel says) it's a word you'd need to be careful to use correctly. 'Registration' is the more commonly used word for the formal process of being admitted in most places now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be "matriculate". Strictly speaking it refers to the ceremony at which a person becomes an actual student. For most purposes, "admit" or "admitted" will result in better writing, in my view.